# AWS Personalize sending events

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I'm on the AWS personalize documentation and it says access node.js code here.

`More code examples (in Node.js, Python, and Go) and AWS Lambda usage guidelines are found here.`

[image]

Where is here??? I'm trying to use nodejs without using lambda. How do I send the equivalent from my node server without lambda, is it even possible?

Here's the Java code.

```
package example;

  public class ProcessKinesisRecords implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Void>{
  
      private static final String TRACKING_ID = be5aa88c-05dd-4c5e-9372-15ffa6a846b9;
      private EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("http://concierge-gamma-events.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "us-west-2");
      private AWSConciergeEventTracking client = AWSConciergeEventTrackingClientBuilder.standard()
                  .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration).build();
      private final CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
  
      @Override
      public Void recordHandler(KinesisEvent event, Context context)
      {
          for(KinesisEventRecord rec : event.getRecords()) {
              try {
                  // Kinesis data is Base64 encoded and needs to be decoded before being used.
                  String data = decoder.decode(record.getKinesis().getData()).toString();
  
                  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);
                  String userId = (String) jsonObject.get(USER_ID);
                  String sessionId = (String) jsonObject.get(SESSION_ID);
                  String eventType = (String) jsonObject.get(EVENT_TYPE);
                  long timestamp= new Date().getTime();
                  ByteBuffer properties = jsonObject.get(EVENT_TYPE).getBytes("UTF-8");
  
                  List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
                  eventList.add(new Event().withProperties(properties).withType(eventType));
                  TrackRequest request = new TrackRequest()
                          .withTrackingId(EVENT_TRACKER_ARN)
                          .withChannel("server")
                          .withUserId(userId)
                          .withSessionId(sessionId)
                          .withEventList(eventList);
                  client.track(request);
              } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                  log.error("Error decoding data in the kinesis stream. ", e);
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                  log.error("Error parsing JSON input from the kinesis stream. ", e);
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  log.error("Error processing record. ", e);
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
              }
          return null;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you been able to get it running?

Comment: @Marcel there's still no regular documentation, they want you to use kinesis. I did not end up using personalize.

Comment: I am in the middle of implementing the Kinesis event > Lambda > Personalize implementation. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all is provided in AWS SDK for Node environment. After some research I have come up with the following code.

This is just a draft, and shows it works.

```
let AWS = require ('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    'region': 'eu-central-1', // process.env.REGION,
    'accessKeyId': 'XXXX', // process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'secretAccessKey': 'XXXXXXX' // process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

let personalizeEvents = new AWS.PersonalizeEvents();

var params = {
    eventList: [ /* required */
        {
            eventType: 'click', /* required */
            sentAt: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789, /* required */
            eventId: 'STRING_VALUE',
            eventValue: 11,
            impression: [
                'STRING_VALUE',
                /* more items */
            ],
            itemId: '1',
            //properties: any /* This value will be JSON encoded on your behalf with JSON.stringify() */,
            recommendationId: 'STRING_VALUE'
        },
    ],
    sessionId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    trackingId: 'trackerid', /* required */
    userId: '666'
};

personalizeEvents.putEvents(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Please read this first, [AWS Official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/what-is-personalize.html) to understand.

And then check the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/PersonalizeEvents.html).